# Intel c/c++ compiler: "could not locate executable icc" (and ecc)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, configuration, compiler-errors, intel

I recently installed a Intel's c/c++ compiler for linux: "Intel® C++ Composer XE for Linux".

When i was doing the installation, only marked the options(or packages) relates to the compiler and debugger, and said to the instaler that i will compile 64bit aplications.

Now when i try to compile a program i get:

meniwis@meniwis-Satellite-L845:~/syscave/src/c-ext/code$ ./build.sh

```
Could not locate executable icc
Could not locate executable ecc
INFO:root:using /opt/alges/ as sqlite3 directory
INFO:root:using /opt/alges/ as HDF5 directory
running build_ext
running build_src
build_src
building extension "cvoronoi" sources
building extension "cflowsim" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
customize IntelCCompiler
customize IntelCCompiler using build_ext
customize IntelCCompiler
customize IntelCCompiler using build_ext
building 'cvoronoi' extension
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: icc -fPIC

compile options: '-g -I/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/../include - 
I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
icc: /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp
sh: 1: icc: not found
sh: 1: icc: not found
error: Command "icc -fPIC -g -I/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/../include -  
I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c   
/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64- 
2.7/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.o" failed with exit status 127
```

Making a "step-by-step" of what i am doing:

In comand line i type:

```
meniwis@meniwis-Satellite-L845:~/syscave/src/c-ext/code$ ./build.sh
```

The "build.sh" file is the next:

```
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/alges/
export SQLITE3_DIR=/opt/alges/
export SYSCAVE_ROOT=/home/meniwis/syscave/

python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

A part of the "setup.py" file:

```
.
.
.
voronoi_src_dir=abspath(pjoin(syscave_root,'src/c-ext/code'))
cflowsim_src_dir=abspath(pjoin(syscave_root,'src/c-ext/code/flowsim/code/Flowsim'))

extensions = [
    Extension('cvoronoi',
        sources=[
                pjoin(voronoi_src_dir,'cvoronoi.cpp'),
                pjoin(voronoi_src_dir,'VoronoiDiagramGenerator.cpp')
            ],
        language = "c++",
        include_dirs=[pjoin(voronoi_src_dir,'../include')],
        extra_objects=lib_args['extra_compile_args']
    ),
    Extension('cflowsim',
        sources=[
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'cflowsim.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'parsers.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'Cell.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'ChunkDriver.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'DataLoader.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'DisplayResult.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'Drawbell.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'DrawbellType.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'Drawpoint.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'ExtractionResult.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'Model.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'Simulator.cpp'),
                pjoin(cflowsim_src_dir,'Tracer.cpp'),
        ],
        language = "c++",
        extra_objects=lib_args['extra_compile_args'],
        **lib_args
    )
]


#move to packages
#all default to ext_dir
ext_run_dir=abspath(pjoin(syscave_root,'src/python/syscave/extensions/'))
moves=[]
for ext in extensions:
    if ext.name not in moves:
        moves.append((ext.name,ext_run_dir))

moves.append(None)

ext_src_dir=pjoin(syscave_root,'src','c-ext','code') #='.'
file_ext=''
if os.name=='posix':
    file_ext='so'
    build_path=abspath(ext_src_dir)
elif os.name=='nt':
    file_ext='pyd'
    build_path=abspath(ext_src_dir)
else:
    raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform: {0}'.format(os.name))

for i,m in enumerate(moves):
    if m is None:
        continue
    name,new_path=m
    file_name=".".join([name,file_ext])
    file_path_from=os.path.join(build_path,file_name)
    file_path_to  =os.path.join(new_path,file_name)
    moves[i]=(file_path_from,file_path_to)
.
.
.
```

So the error is that icc and ecc cant be found? or is something else?, and if this is, how i solve it? Any directions?.

Thanks in advance.
Grettings.

---------------------EDIT----------------------------------

---

After the help of @Vahid abdi, i do the next:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/bin/
```

Now i get:

```
meniwis@meniwis-Satellite-L845:~/syscave/src/c-ext/code$ ./build.sh 
Found executable /opt/intel/bin/icc
Could not locate executable ecc
INFO:root:using /opt/alges/ as sqlite3 directory
INFO:root:using /opt/alges/ as HDF5 directory
running build_ext
running build_src
build_src
building extension "cvoronoi" sources
building extension "cflowsim" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
customize IntelCCompiler
customize IntelCCompiler using build_ext
customize IntelCCompiler
customize IntelCCompiler using build_ext
building 'cvoronoi' extension
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: icc -fPIC

compile options: '-g -I/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/../include - 
I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
icc: /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h(61),
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map(60),
                 from /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c- 
ext/code/../include/VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h(36),
                 from /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp(9):
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h(59): catastrophic error: cannot open source  
file "bits/c++config.h"
  #include <bits/c++config.h>
                         ^

compilation aborted for /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp (code 4)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h(61),
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map(60),
                 from /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-  
ext/code/../include/VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h(36),
                 from /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp(9):
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h(59): catastrophic error: cannot open source    
file "bits/c++config.h"
  #include <bits/c++config.h>
                             ^

compilation aborted for /home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp (code 4)
error: Command "icc -fPIC -g -I/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/../include -  
I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c    
/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-  
2.7/home/meniwis/syscave/src/c-ext/code/cvoronoi.o" failed with exit status 4
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the problem is icc can't open `bits/c++config.h`

if you have `bits/c++config.h` first try to find it's path (which is probably is: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7) and add it to icc like below

```
export __INTEL_POST_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7"
```

Comment: Men, thank you very, very much, you are saving my life, almost literaly. The location of bits is usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 When i type export __INTEL_POST_CFLAGS "-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8" i get "bash: export: `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8': Not a valid identifier" what could be wrong? thank you again.

Comment: oops, i forgot '=' change it to this export __INTEL_POST_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7"

Comment: Thank you.The export works.Now i get:catastrophic error: cannot open source file "H5Cpp.h", which i think is esentially the same thing that before. So i will do the respective export__INTEL_POST... I have 2 questions,the file "H5Cpp.h" its not in my system,when i download or install that file, i must put it on usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 or in another location?. Second question, i think i will get an error very similar to this for each import i use in my cpp files, any way i could say to icc to search always in a determined path, to avoid do an export__INTEL_POST_FLAG for each import?

Comment: here's the tips for installing pacage which provides the specific file 'sudo apt-get install apt-file && sudo apt-file update && sudp apt-file search H5Cpp.h' which returns this **libhdf5-dev: /usr/include/H5Cpp.h** then install libhdf5-dev and it will place H5Cpp.h in /usr/include/H5Cpp.h, if you get similar error do the same thing.

Comment: A very last question. Every once in awhile, i have to, again, do the "export __INTEL_POST_CFLAGS" and "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/bin/", can i, in someway, do those exports permanently?. Again, thank you man.

Comment: add those in to your ~/.bashrc file

Answer (score 1):

how did you install icc?

icc is not in your $PATH variable

first lookup for the icc path `updatedb && locate icc`

then add it's basename to your $PATH variable like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/youricc/basename
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.On how i did the install of icc?, well, i let the "Intel c++ composer xe" installer do everything. As i said, i only installed the compiler and the debugger. After that, i did this: 
http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-F79DF975-A9CB-4C9A-A394-286E44B8FDBE.htm#GUID-F79DF975-A9CB-4C9A-A394-286E44B8FDBE   

I believe that would be enough to set variables to the PATH.
icc it is located on /opt/intel/bin. I suppose you say i must do "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/bin" from the command line or not?

Comment: thanks again. I did that, now icc is found, but i get a new error, which i describe on the question. Can you please help me?