# on c++(on ubuntu) what i must configure for the compiler find the imports?(like iostream,stdio,math,etc)

Tags: c++, python, ubuntu, compiler-construction

I have Ubuntu, Python 2.7, Intel C/C++ Compiler.
Supose i have a file called voronoi.cpp,that uses these imports(or any others):

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>


#ifndef FLT_MAX
    double FLT_MAX=std::numeric_limits<double>::max( );
#endif


double round(double x, int precision) {
    double p = pow(double(10), precision);
    double r = floor(x * p + 0.5) / p;
    return r;
}

bool equals(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double precision) {
    double p = pow(10, -0.9* precision);
    return fabs(x1 - x2) <= p && fabs(y1 - y2) <= p;
}

double p2p_distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}
.
.
.
```

My question is: When i go to compile this file, the compiler, where gonna look in my system for the imports? Or, the same question but in a different form, where i must put the files "Python.h", "VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h",  and  for the compiler find them? or what i must configure for the compiler find the imports?

Thank you in advance.
Grettings.

Comment: You will not find `conio.h` in anything other than ancient dos/windows compilers.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, thanks for the answer. Your right. I mean, iostream, stdio, math, etc., where the compiler look for these libraries???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is built into the compiler. The GCC compiler will look in /usr/include, /usr/local/include, /usr/include/c++/4.8/...

The Intel compiler, since it isn't the default system compiler, will probably use its own directories.

Any #include statement that uses the double quotes will look in the same directory as the source code file first. After that I think it will try /usr/include, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Recently i have a problem with icc and "import <bits/c++config.h>", icc said: "can not open source file 'bits/c++config.h'", it solves with export __INTEL_POST_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8" which is the place where the bits/c++config.h was located, here i got the answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817322/intel-c-c-compiler-could-not-locate-executable-icc-and-ecc   Again, thank you.